# basic calculator. How to allow user to make multiple choices. code works already

Tags: java

The code works and was pretty easy.  I made another using a switch but teacher wants if statements.  So the user enters 2 numbers then makes a choice after from the println menu I created.  I need the user to be able to make a second choice.  Such as choose "a" for addition then also being able to choose "b" subtraction afterwards.  It would be nice to be able to make the menu reproduce after every choice was made also.  I need the first user input numbers to be persistent.

thanks.
  edit:  this is final version that works

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign3

{
    public static void main (String [] args)

    {
        double numOne;
        double numTwo;
        String answerTo = null;

        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.println("|   MENU Calculator Fun    |");
        System.out.println("============================");
        System.out.println("| Options:                 |");
        System.out.println("|        a. Add            |");
        System.out.println("|        b. Substract      |");
        System.out.println("|        c. Multiply       |");
        System.out.println("|        d. Divide         |");
        System.out.println("|        e. Mod            |");
        System.out.println("|        f. Compare        |");
        System.out.println("|        g. Print Numbers  |");
        System.out.println("|        h. Quit           |");
        System.out.println("============================");

        Scanner numFinder = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a number then press enter then enter another number followed by enter.");

        numOne = numFinder.nextDouble();
        numTwo = numFinder.nextDouble();

        while(true)
        {   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please choose an option.");
        String menuSelect = scan.next();

        if(menuSelect.length() > 1) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error, too many letters...");
        }

        else if(menuSelect.equals("a"))
        {
            answerTo = Double.toString(numOne +numTwo);
        }
        else if(menuSelect.equals("b")) 
        {
            answerTo = Double.toString(numOne - numTwo);
        }
        else if(menuSelect.equals("c"))
        {
            answerTo = Double.toString(numOne * numTwo);
        }
        else if(menuSelect.equals("d"))
        {
            answerTo = Double.toString(numOne / numTwo);
        }
        else if(menuSelect.equals("e"))
        {
            answerTo = Double.toString(numOne % numTwo);
        }
        else if (menuSelect.equals("f"))

            if(numOne > numTwo)
            {
                answerTo = ">";//System.out.println("First is grater");
            }
            else if(numOne < numTwo)
            {
                answerTo ="<";//System.out.println("Second is grater");
            }
            else
            {
                answerTo ="=";//System.out.println("Both are equal");
            }

        else if(menuSelect.equals("g"))
        {
            answerTo = "First number: " + numOne + "  Second number: " + numTwo;
        }
        else if(menuSelect.equals("h"))
        {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("answer: " + answerTo);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you learned about while loops yet?

Comment: I learn mostly on my own and I have allot more experience with c# and VB.  So I have tried to input a while(true) but the end statements run infinitely.  So I figured I needed help with implementing the while statement.

Comment: `while(true)` could work, but you'll have to have `if(menuSelect.equals("h")) break;` if that makes sense

Comment: So replace my sytem.exit with break,  which is how I had it before.  But with my while true statement in place at the top the final println continues on forever.  Where would I put that println to only produce after the user input

Comment: I wish I could somehow express the feeling that comes from ,"I did this 20 different ways earlier and none of them worked"; but now that I plugged it in it works perfectly.  thanks a bunch

Comment: How do I +1 rep you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a `while` loop around the entire chunk.

then have

```
else if(menuSelect.equals("h"))
{
    break;
}
```

this will break out of the loop

Comment: and I placed'while(true)
    {   
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);'

Comment: I have a new one.  how would I go about putting a try again message for any query that does not fit into the a-g in my menu

Comment: after all of the else ifs, put an else and output your error message then `continue` like this

`else
{
    System.out.println("Try again");
    continue;
}`